# Assigning a object to another object Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, object

I am trying to create Bar diagram using canvas js. Now the problem is, when i assign the value to display using graph, it take in some other object format like this,

```
[object Object], [object Object],...
```

So When i am sending the data through res.send() it seems to be fine. Its original format is,

```
[ { label: '102', y: '80' },
  { label: '102', y: '60' },
  { label: '102', y: '80' },
  { label: '102', y: '50' } ]
```

So My Javascript code is ,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/result',
    error: function () {
        console.log("Not working");
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "theme1",
        title: {
            text: "Something"
        },
        animationEnabled: false,   
        data: [
            {

                type: "bar",
                dataPoints: result // actual problem lies here!
            }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
});
```

What am i doing wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: what does `console.log(result);` shows?

Comment: it shows like `[object , object, object, object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass your result to this function then

```
       function convertdata(json) {
                var chartData = [];

                    for (var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; i++) {
                        var value = parseFloat(json[i].label) + parseFloat(json[i].y);
                        chartData.push({ c: [{ v: json[i].Label }, { v: value }] });
                    }
                }
```

Assign chart data to your graph for rendering

Comment: I solved it!! I used `res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));` and it worked.